# Remove watermark imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

How can I remove the watermark of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop.

If you have an original image and the image with the watermark, you can subtract them to see what what watermark did.  You can then subtract this watermark from other images.  Note that this won't always work and will result in artifacts unless you know exactly how the watermark was applied.